# const/non-const member function based on compile time conditions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Let's consider following classes:

```
struct InputArgument{};
struct SpecialInputArgument{};
struct MoreSpecialInputArgument{};

struct OutputArgument{};
struct SpecialOutputArgument{};
struct MoreSpecialOutputArgument{};
```

I need to have a member function that accepts all previous classes as arguments and act on them. To simplify the implementation (don't repeat same code over and over) I made the member function template and dispatched the actual code to non-member functions:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type DoSomething(T&, const InputArgument&)
{
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type DoSomething(const T&, OutputArgument&)
{
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type DoSomething(T&, const SpecialInputArgument&)
{
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type DoSomething(const T&, SpecialOutputArgument&)
{
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type DoSomething(T&, const MoreSpecialInputArgument&)
{
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type DoSomething(const T&, MoreSpecialOutputArgument&)
{
}

struct MyGloriuosClass
{
    template<typename T>
    void DoSomething(T& arg)
    {
        ::DoSomething(myIntMember, arg);
        ::DoSomething(myFloatMember, arg);
    }

    int     myIntMember = 0;
    float   myFloatMember = 0.f;
};
```

And this works perfect:

```
MyGloriuosClass myGloriuosObject;

InputArgument inputArgument;
SpecialInputArgument specialInputArgument;
MoreSpecialInputArgument moreSpecialInputArgument;

OutputArgument outputArgument;
SpecialOutputArgument specialOutputArgument;
MoreSpecialOutputArgument moreSpecialOutputArgument;

myGloriuosObject.DoSomething(inputArgument);
myGloriuosObject.DoSomething(specialInputArgument);
myGloriuosObject.DoSomething(moreSpecialInputArgument);

myGloriuosObject.DoSomething(outputArgument);
myGloriuosObject.DoSomething(specialOutputArgument);
myGloriuosObject.DoSomething(moreSpecialOutputArgument);
```

Expect in one case, when the object I use is const:

```
const MyGloriuosClass myConstGloriousObject = MyGloriuosClass();
myConstGloriousObject.DoSomething(outputArgument);
myConstGloriousObject.DoSomething(specialOutputArgument);
myConstGloriousObject.DoSomething(moreSpecialOutputArgument);
```

As you can see, all the actual code is done in functions that accept `const` objects when the argument is of type `Output` so there is no reason to limit this to only `non-const` objects or to write my member function twice, once as `const` and once as `non-const`. In my ideal world I will deduce if the function is `const/non-const` based on the `type trait` `std::is_base_of` of the argument, but I don't know if this is possible or not.

**Is it possible to declare a member function const/non-const based on compile time conditions?**

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you just want plain old function overloading instead?

Comment: @Thomas Because functions like MyGloriuosClass::DoSomething are in many other classes and classes of type "Input/Output" the same. Overloading would lead to a combinatorial problem of code repetition. With current approach when one new "Input/Output" class is added only 2 free functions are needed.

Comment: @downvoter Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

A member function is either const, or non-const member function. There is no third option. Classes can define either a const function, a non-const function, or even both, as you know.

What I suspect that you might be missing is that a const member function can be invoked for a non-const class instance.

So, if your member function does not need to modify any other members of the class instance, just declare your member function as a const function, and it can be invoked for either a const or a non-const class instance.

Comment: As you can see when the argument is of the "Input" type the members are modified in the non-member functions.

Comment: Seems like you just need to have a DoSomething() member function that takes a const T & parameter.